# Editing Icons and Icon Sequence in the Launcher?

Tags: unity, 12.04, launcher, icons

How do you edit the icons in the launcher? I am particularly interested in "bumping up" higher some of my more frequently used software icons that I have locked to the launcher. Unity seems to dictate a fairly rigid way of doing things while allowing less room for personalisation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If hold the left mouse button down for a couple of seconds on the icon you want to move then you will be able to drag it up or down the launcher.